# Mean position of particle in a Lennard-Jones potential

Tags: equilibrium, interactions

I want to compute the mean position $\langle x\rangle_\mathrm{eq}$ (let's say in $1$D) in thermal equilibrium (canonical ensemble) of a particle coupled to another particle via a $6$-$12$ Lennard-Jones potential.

However, I face difficulties as the phase space integrals do not converge.

Isn't the Hamiltonian simply given by the interaction potential and I can use Boltzmann distribution to compute it?

Where is my mistake?

Comment: *Isn't the Hamiltonian simply given by the interaction potential?* Shouldn’t the Hamiltonian also include the kinetic energy of the two particles?

Comment: Yes, of course, but it plays no role for the ensemble average if the integrand is independent of velocity. That quoted statement was inaccurate, though. Sorry

Answer (score 0):

Because the potential falls off quickly with distance (like $r^{-6}$, characteristic of a van der Wasls interaction) the problem you encounter is essentially the same as the one you would encounter if you asked for the mean distance between two noninteracting particles.  If any positive distance is allowed, then that average clearly diverges; the particles can be arbitrarily far apart.

The solution to this problem is to restrict your problem to a finite region of volume.  Typically, the length of the occupied region is limited to a large number $L$.  [In quantum statistical mechanics, it is easiest to do this by imposing periodic boundary conditions, so that $\psi(x+L)=\psi(x)$.]  That will give you a finite answer, although in most physical situations, you are really interested in studying not just two particles, but a particle gas of $N$ particles with some known density ($N/L$ in one dimension, or $n=N/L^3$ in three dimensions).